# Ionic and cordova(Latest versions) installation problems

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to install the Ionic framework with `npm`. It successfully installed. But when I try installing new versions of Ionic and Cordova, I was unable to install and Error messages are coming frequently in the ubuntu terminal.

Comment: well.. what error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please update the question with the errors? It's hard for the community to help you if we don't know what the specific errors are.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem but i recovered it using following command:
**npm install -g cordova ionic --verbos**

if its not work then you need to try yarn. you can download and install form https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/ this website

After install, run the following command

**yarn add global cordova**

**yarn add global ionic**